# Running same test in parrallel in N threads M times

Tags: java, spring, junit5

I have a spring app with unit tests. I want to check how my code works when it run in N threads.
Now I use `java.util.concurrent.Executor`, `ExecutableFuture`'s, spring batch features and so on in my tests.

Is there simple way, something like this annotation:

```
@SuperPuperParallelTest(threadCount=5, timesToRun=100)
@Test
public void myTestMethod() { ... }
```

Or another (preferably annotation driven) approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [tempus-fugit](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/) . It is a Java library that helps us to test concurrent code with convenient annotations.

For an example, see here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-testing-multithreaded

Comment: Yes, seems that I need.